# How to send custom status codes using Kohana 3?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, http-status-codes

I am trying to return custom status codes using Kohana 3.1, like so :

`$this->response->status(420);`

Kohana says so :

> "Kohana_Response::status unknown status value : 418"

How do I force Kohana to send such a status code?

FYI, the server I am using is Nginx, and I have to catch this status code there in Nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [source code to the `Response::status()`](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.1/master/classes/kohana/response.php#L247) method you will that Kohana has a whitelist of valid response codes.

Either override the `Response` class (using kohana's [transparent extension](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/extension)) and add your new status to the `$messages` array.

Or, since it is a public property add the entry to `Response::$messages` in `bootstrap.php`.

Comment: Yup, using the transparent extension is the way I choose, lets see how that goes :)

Comment: `Response::$messages` is a public property, so you can modify it somewhere in your code (bootstrap.php for example)

Comment: If you are interested in only sending the statuscode without a body you can use: `$this->response->status(420)->send_headers()`. Use `$this` when you are in a controller. Also note that code is still executed after sending headers.